# How can I get the scores during solving

Tags: optaplanner

I'm creating a report that presents the score changes during solving, so I have to collect the scores every 10 minutes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
solver.addEventListener((BestSolutionChangedEvent e) -> {
    System.out.println(e.getNewBestScore());
});
```

Comment: @Geoffrey-De_Smet -- FYI this answer was flagged for deletion as "low-quality because of its length and content".  I'm marking it as OK solely due to your rep (5× mine!) but you might want to add more info. :-)

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. On the other hand, is there the way to get the step count and move count, during solving?

Comment: *Why do you need those?* (if there's a good motivation, a jira can be created.) As far as I know, they are meaningless to users, because they look very different for Tabu Search and Late Acceptance even when the progress&quality is about the same.

Comment: I just want to create a function in my system to show the information of solving, so that, I can monitor it, especial in real-time planning.

Comment: Just enable `DEBUG` logging (or even `TRACE` if you like verbose), as explained in the docs. See the examples on how to get a nice readable log format (hint: don't include classnames). But if you really want to go down the "bad" path, `PhaseLifecycleListener.stepEnded(...)` has what you're asking for :)

Comment: Now I'm read step counts from the logging message, I'll try PhaseLifecycleListener.stepEnded. Thank you, Geoffrey.